# wso2 API Manager "Unsupported Client Authentication Method!"

Tags: curl, oauth, wso2, wso2-identity-server

I am attempting to use the OAuth2 grant_type=password for a token request as described [here](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-4.3.2) with the WSO2 API Manager. Using the following curl command.

```
curl -k -d "grant_type=password&username=<uname>&password=<pwd>&scope=PRODUCTION" http://localhost:8280/token
```

The response from this request is:

```
{"error":"invalid_request","error_description":"Missing parameters: client_id"}
```

Next, I supply my consumer key and the curl request becomes the following:

```
curl -k -d "grant_type=password&username=<uname>&password=<pwd>&scope=PRODUCTION&client_id=<myconsumerkey>" http://localhost:8280/token
```

However, the response is baffling:

```
{"error":"unsupported_client_authentication_method","error_description":"Unsupported Client Authentication Method!"}
```

So, my question is does the API Man just not support this grant_type?  Or, am I doing something incorrectly here?  Should I be looking at the identity server for this grant type?

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to send the client credentials (client key and secret) in HTTP Basic Authorization header. Curl command would be such as following. Here "--user client-Key:client-Secret" has been used to creates the Basic Authorization header using curl command. You can use following command with your values.

> curl --user  tFVhXORF35S9TTyeaZIH2IEXEw4a:4h6fq4jgRYKrr4v91A_zQgw4Xtoa   -k -d "grant_type=password&username=admin&password=admin" -H  "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" https://{IP}:{Port}/oauth2/token

Add in to this more, I guess WSO2API does not support to receive client credentials in request body. According to the OAuth 2.0 spec, It is not recommended. Please check [here](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-2.3.1)

Comment: Thanks @Asela.  In this case I do not have the client-key or the client-secret.  Hence, I am attempting to use the resource owner password grant to retrieve the token(s).  I suppose the only alternative I've seen is using the store api to login and then retrieve the key and secret then, generate the request for the api token.  Any thoughts?

Comment: Normally, when you uses resource owner password grant type, You also need to authenticate the client http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6749#section-4.3.2   Basically, as you are the application developer, you must register an application and receive client credential from the API store.